# How do you perform Binding with a DataGridView in WPF?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I want to bind a datagrid view in a user control that is docking to a main WPF form.  However everytime I try to bind the data it must pre exist and won't update.  Is there a way to perform this in the XAML directly to know when an event is triggered to update the datagridview rather than do it in the code behind?

Partial code of XAML:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:TestWPFMain"

<UserControl.Resources>
    <c:GridData x:Key="dataforGrid"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="datagridMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataforGrid}, Path=Results, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind for UserControl above:

```
public GridControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridData gd = new GridData();
        gd.UpdateResults();

        //datagridMain.ItemsSource = gd.Results;  
        -- This code above will work if I uncomment but I want it to be bound 
           directly and was curious as I thought the mode of 'two way' would 
           do this.  I am not certain and most examples assume property is already
           set up and not being created and updated.
    }
```

Code Class for GridData:

```
class PersonName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class GridData
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonName> Results { get; set; }

    public void UpdateResults()
    {
        using (EntityDataModel be = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            var list = be.tePersons.Select(x => new PersonName { Name = x.FirstName });

            Results = new ObservableCollection<PersonName>(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use binding like this, you need to:

1. Set the `DataContext` correctly on the `DataGrid` (or on one of its parent)
2. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your model class, and raise `PropertyChanged` in the property setter.

#### 1)

Set your window's DataContext to the `GridData` object:

```
public GridControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    GridData gd = new GridData();
    gd.UpdateResults();
    this.DataContext = gd;
}
```

#### 2)

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This ensures that your view gets notified when the `Results` property gets updated:

```
public class GridData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<PersonName> _results;
    public ObservableCollection<PersonName> Results 
    {  
        get { return _results; }
        set
        {
            _results = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GridData");
        }
    }

    // ...

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then you can simply bind to the path relative to the data context.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" />
```

Note that you don't need two-way binding in this case -- that's for propagating changes from the View back to your model (ie, most useful for when there's a UI control like a text box or checkbox).

Comment: Thanks dbaseman, I had feeling adding an event hooked up to an interface may do the trick but just did not know what to use.  Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (I used Window, but it will work the same for UserControl)

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="datagridMain" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridData.Results, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

or id you want the whole DataContext:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="datagridMain" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=GridData}" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

You will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the xaml knows GridData has changed
The ObservableCollection inside GridData as this function built-in so anytime you add remove items they will update the DataGrid control

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GridData = new GridData { Results = new ObservableCollection<PersonName>() };
        GridData.Results.Add(new PersonName { Name = "Test1" });
        GridData.Results.Add(new PersonName { Name = "Test2" });
    }

    private GridData _gridData;
    public GridData GridData
    {
        get { return _gridData; }
        set { _gridData = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("GridData"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The info.</param>
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Classes:
I made a small change to the update method, so it just clears and updates the existing ObservableCollection, otherwise you would have to Implement INotifypropertyChanged to this class if you assign a new ObservableCollection.

```
public class PersonName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GridData
{
    public GridData()
    {
       Results = new ObservableCollection<PersonName>()
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonName> Results { get; set; }

    public void UpdateResults()
    {
        using (EntityDataModel be = new EntityDataModel())
        {
            // Just update existing list, instead of creating a new one.
           Results.Clear();
           be.tePersons.Select(x => new PersonName { Name = x.FirstName }).ToList().ForEach(item => Results.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```